# Oracle Apex auto increment column respective to each employee

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to add autoincrement to a column in my interactive grid.
However the challenge here is to do that for each employee.

Current data is:

```
EMP_NAME    EMP_SEQ
John        1
John        2
Mary        1
Mary        2
Mary        3
```

Currently both columns are editable but i need to make emp_seq as read only.

EMP_NAME is select list with list of all employee names.

For each employee there are multiple rows. So whenever a new row is added for a particular employee, as soon as that employee is selected, the id column should increment for that particular employee only and not as a whole.
So if i click on add row, and select John as the employee name, upon selection, the emp_seq should auto increment/select 3 as the set value.

Similarly if i select Mary after add row, it should set 4 in emp_seq.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are saying, but disagree with your intention. That's not what you should be doing, and - especially - not storing into the table.

This is a sample table:

```
SQL> select * from employees;

EMP_NAME                    VAL
-------------------- ----------
John                         24
Mary                          3
Mary                         43
John                          8
Mary                          9
```

`emp_seq` should be **calculated** every time you need it; `row_number` analytic function is a good choice:

```
SQL> select emp_name,
  2    row_number() over (partition by emp_name order by val) emp_seq,
  3    val
  4  from employees
  5  order by emp_name, val;

EMP_NAME                EMP_SEQ        VAL
-------------------- ---------- ----------
John                          1          8
John                          2         24
Mary                          1          3
Mary                          2          9
Mary                          3         43
```

What happens when you insert a new row?

```
SQL> insert into employees (emp_name, val) values ('Mary', 74);

1 row created.

SQL> select emp_name,
  2    row_number() over (partition by emp_name order by val) emp_seq,
  3    val
  4  from employees
  5  order by emp_name, val;

EMP_NAME                EMP_SEQ        VAL
-------------------- ---------- ----------
John                          1          8
John                          2         24
Mary                          1          3
Mary                          2          9
Mary                          3         43
Mary                          4         74      --> here's new Mary, with EMP_SEQ = 4
 
6 rows selected.
```

---

Basically, that's what I'd suggest you to do in interactive grid's source query. `emp_seq` wouldn't be table column (as it is not), so you'd turn its "query only" property ON.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. However emp_seq is not null and table column. I guess in that case this solution wont work because emp_seq needs to have a value upon saving.

Comment: What is that column's purpose, exactly?